# Ncurses does not detect keystroke

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

I am trying to use ncurses to get non-blocking input.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ncurses.h>
 int main()
 {
     char ch;
     nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
     while(1)
     {
          ch= getch();
          if (ch == ERR) {
               printf("here \n");
               usleep(100000);
          }
           else {
                 printf("---------------\n");
           }

     }
 }
```

However when I run this code, irrespective of what I press I always just get "here" printed.

Sample output:

```
Latitude-E6430:~$ ./try 

here 
 here 
here 
here 
   here 
   here 
   here 
    here 
   here 
   here 
   here 
    here 
   here 
   here 
   here 
    here 
   here 
   here 
   here 
    here 
   here 
   here 
  here 
dhere
ddhere 
dhere 
here
```

The d's and the spaces are not detected at all.

Can someone tell me why?

Thanks.

Comment: `ch` should be declared as `int`.

Comment: Even after that I get the same error

Comment: Hence comment, not answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer to the question.

I need to do initscr();

After that I am able to print out correctly (the formatting is not-as-expected though).

Correct code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ncurses.h>
 int main()
 {
     char ch;

     initscr();
     nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
     while(1)
     {
          ch= getch();
          if (ch == ' ') {
 //              printf("here \n");
               usleep(100000);
          }
           else {
                 printf("---------------\n");
           }

     }
 }
```

Comment: You should not be using printf with ncurses. Use the ncurses output routines (e.g. `waddstr`)